# Sending model via form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, form-submit

I'm trying to send a model to the view and get it back. I tried to parse as json in a hidden field but the model got too large and even if I can increase the limit I'm trying to do it in a way where there isn't such a limit.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Export", "Summary", new { model = Model }, FormMethod.Post)

public FileResult Export(Models.SummaryModel model)
{
     //model is null
     .....
}
```

The model is a complex one made out of multiple classes so I'm not sure if this is the problem here or my syntax is wrong.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: annotate the method with `[HttpPost]`

Comment: @RandomUser if I leave it blank shouldn't it work for post and get?

Comment: Leaving it empty works only for `Get`

Comment: @RandomUser it still doesn't solve the problem. The model is still null.

Comment: removing `new { model = Model }` works for me

Comment: try `@using (Html.BeginForm("Export", "Summary")`

Comment: But I'm trying to pass `Model` to the controller. What I initially did was `<input value="@Json.Encode(Model)" name="computed" hidden="hidden"/> ` but it can't serialize my huge model.

Comment: if the view is strongly typed to `Models.SummaryModel` no need to send the model

Comment: @RandomUser the view needs the model! And when exporting I need the same model again.

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu, There is no point using `new { model = Model }`. It would only work if all your model properties were value types anyway, but what is the point. All your doing is sending a lot of pointless data across the wire to the view and then sending it (unchanged) back again which has a detrimental impact on performance. Just get the model again in the POST method. But then again, from this code its clear you not understanding some basic concepts so I'm not really sure what your trying to achieve.

Comment: @StephenMuecke it takes 5 min to create the model (lots of data). I'm not recreating it twice. I managed to solve it with `TempData`.

Comment: Don't use `TempData` for this (open your page and press F5!). You need to rethink what your doing.